# Replace part of string with known beginning and end

Tags: java, android

I get some string from server with known and unknow parts. For example:

```
<simp>example1</simp><op>example2</op><val>example2</val>
```

I do not wish to parse XML or any use of parsing. What I wish to do is replace

```
<op>example2</op>
```

with empty string ("") which string will look like:

```
<simp>example1</simp><val>example2</val>
```

What I know it start with op (in <>) and ends with /op (in <>) but the content (example2) may vary.

Can you give me pointer how accomplish this?

Comment: That's XML, not HTML. What happens if you have this `<op><simp>example1</simp>example2</op><val>example2</val>`?

Comment: Thanks, updated to XML. If I have the example above I would like to remove all in op and get only <val>example2</val>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined all the answers and eventually used:

```
st.replaceAll("<op>.*?<\\/op>","");
```

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex. Something like

```
<op>[A-Za-z0-9]*<\/op>
```

should match. But you can adapt it so that it fits your requirements better. For example if you know that only certain characters can be shown, you can change it. 
Afterwards you can use the String#replaceAll method to remove all matching occurrences with the empty string.

Take a look here to test the regex: https://regex101.com/r/WhPIv4/3
and here to check the replaceAll method that takes the regex and the replacement as a parameter: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String#replaceall

Comment: You can use [`<op>.*?<\/op>`](https://regex101.com/r/WhPIv4/2) to match any char.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
str.replace(str.substring(str.indexOf("<op>"),str.indexOf("</op>")+5),"");
```

To remove all, use **`replaceAll()`**

```
str.replaceAll(str.substring(str.indexOf("<op>"),str.indexOf("</op>")+5),"");
```

I tried sample,

```
String str="<simp>example1</simp><op>example2</op><val>example2</val><simp>example1</simp><op>example2</op><val>example2</val><simp>example1</simp><op>example2</op><val>example2</val>";
Log.d("testit", str.replaceAll(str.substring(str.indexOf("<op>"), str.indexOf("</op>") + 5), ""));
```

And the log output was

```
D/testit: <simp>example1</simp><val>example2</val><simp>example1</simp><val>example2</val><simp>example1</simp><val>example2</val>
```

## Edit

As #Elsafar said ,  **`str.replaceAll("<op>.*?</op>", "")`** will work.

Comment: this will remove only the first occurrence of the tag, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Dim use replaceAll()  and the '5' defines the length of "</op>" Not the intermediate string length

Comment: still wouldn't work, I believe, because indexOf also only matches the first occurrence.

Comment: I tested it now. It works for me. Please try sample strings

Comment: @Dim `</op>` is 5 characters long. The +5 moves the end of the substring to the end of that token.  this code does what you ask.

Comment: @Jyoti JK It works, only if the <op> contents are the same. If you try to change one of the example2 to something else, it does not work for me. Try e.g. <simp>example1</simp><op>example2</op><b>test</b><op>example3</op><val>example2</val>

Comment: @peshkira yes you are right!!! as #Eselfar comment, `str.replaceAll("<op>.*?</op>", "")` will be the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
    String str = "<simp>example1</simp><op>example2</op><val>example2</val>";
    String garbage = str.substring(str.indexOf("<op>"),str.indexOf("</op>")+5).trim();
    String newString = str.replace(garbage,"");
```

Comment: I am sorry that not mentioned but the length does not have to be 5

Comment: "ends with /op (in <>)"  will must have length 5.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Got it